# ListView BaseAdapter is hanging

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, infinite-scroll

I am getting some odd behavior in my scroll-able listview. It is controlled by a BaseAdapter.

As I scroll up or down it will sometimes hang and then bounce back in the opposite direction. I have no idea why and do not know how to trouble shoot it.

My base adapter is below and it loads about 90 fragments with an image and a bunch of text.

```
public class PosterListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private final ArrayList<Poster> listItems;

        private final LayoutInflater inflater;

        public PosterListAdapter(ArrayList<Poster> listItems, LayoutInflater inflater) {
            this.listItems = listItems;
            this.categoryList = categoryItems;
            this.inflater = inflater;
        }       


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            //Log.d("getCount", String.valueOf(this.listItems.size()));
            return this.listItems.size();               
        }

        @Override
        public Poster getItem(int i) {

            return this.listItems.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            MyViewHolder mViewHolder;
            SparseArray<String> categoryMap = db.getCategoryMap();

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.catalog_list_fragment, viewGroup, false);
                mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
            } else {
                mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            //LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();

            Poster item = this.listItems.get(i);

            String filename = item.getPosterFilename();

            mViewHolder.posterAuthor.setText("Author: "+item.getPresenterFname()+' '+item.getPresenterLname());
            mViewHolder.posterAltAuthors.setText("Supporting Authors: "+item.getPosterAuthors());
            mViewHolder.posterTitle.setText(item.getPosterTitle());
            mViewHolder.posterSynopsis.setText(item.getPosterSynopsis());
            mViewHolder.posterNumber.setText("Poster: "+String.valueOf(item.getPosterNumber()));
            mViewHolder.posterPresentation.setText("Live Presentation: "+item.getSessionDate()+" at "+item.getSessionTime()+"\nAt Station: "+item.getPosterStation());          

            String category = categoryMap.get(item.getCatID());

            mViewHolder.posterCategory.setText("Category: "+category);

            File imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath(), "/"+filename+"/"+filename+".png");

//Here I thought maybe the resizing of the image or even the image itself
// was causing the hang up so I tried the list without it and it is still 
// hanging.
            //mViewHolder.imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(imgFile.toString())));
            if (imgFile.exists()){
                /*Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.toString());
                int newWidth = 500;
                Bitmap sizedBMP = getResizedBitmap(bmp, newWidth);

                mViewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(sizedBMP);*/
            }
            else{
                //set no image available
            }

            return convertView;
        }

        private class MyViewHolder {

            TextView posterTitle, posterAuthor, posterSynopsis, posterCategory, posterNumber, posterAltAuthors,posterPresentation;
            ImageView imageView;

            public MyViewHolder(View item) {
                posterTitle = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.poster_title);
                posterAuthor = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.poster_author);
                posterAltAuthors = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.poster_altAuthors);
                posterSynopsis = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.poster_synopsis);
                posterCategory = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.poster_category);
                posterNumber = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.poster_number);
                posterPresentation = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.poster_presentation);

                imageView = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.poster_thumb);
            }
        }
    }
```

I know that is a big chunk of code and it may be ugly.. If you could point me in the right direction as to how to trouble shoot it that would be helpful as well. I am using eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet if you comment out that line `File imgFile = new File(...` (and the code that depends on `imgFile`) that your list scrolling will improve.

That's still an I/O operation and since `getView()` runs in the UI thread, it may cause hiccups.

What you should do is: once you have the `ImageView` in `getView()`, you start an `AsyncTask` to open the file, decode it, and assign the bitmap to the `ImageView`.

Then you have to handle things like: the `ImageView` gets recycled, but the task isn't completed.

Read this article: [Multithreading for Performance | Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html).  It's dealing with images from a remote server, but all the principles are still the same.

Also:  does this line `SparseArray<String> categoryMap = db.getCategoryMap();` do a database lookup?  That could cause a hiccup as well.

TL;DR `getView()` needs to be fast; put slow operations in a non-UI thread.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I am working on implementing them now. The categoryMap is a db call so I moved it outside of the BaseAdapter. When I shut the imageView down I did notice an improvement. There is still a "bounce" every now and then but maybe that is the Android UI causing it.

Answer (score 1):

**Database related operations should done in separate thread**. as it might take time to get data if number of records are greater.

and getView() method will be called more then one time. we can say it will be called in loop till size of your array list (getCount()).

**Second thing:** File operation is also should be done in separate thread.because IO task is also some times time consuming.

**Solution:**

`SparseArray<String> categoryMap = db.getCategoryMap();`
 put this line out of getView() method as i cant see any list dependent parameter in this line. this should be done in either **constructor** or **separate thread**.

Run your database operations and File IO in separate thread like using **AsyncTask**

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous answer, looks like creating new `File` is the only heavy operation which hangs your app.

Try to use some image loading library, for example [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). It will simplify your code, also you won't have to deal with background job. Library will do it all for you.

1.Import library, e.g. if you use gradle insert this into your `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven Central
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

2.In your adapter replace code related to loading picture with this:

```
Glide
    .with(context)
    .load(<full path to your local file>)
    .into(mViewHolder.imageView);
```

3.And it is all. Glide will handle recycling and other things internally, also it is optimized for fast loading and smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Image related processes really consumes so much memory on the UIThread of the app, you should be setting your image using asynchronous(background) approach. Or if its much of a hassle for you, there are tons of libraries available that will do this. I specifically recommend using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for it is very dynamic, easy to use and is regularly updated. Loading an image would require one line of code:

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(<your image path or url or resource id>).into(YourImageView);
```

Picasso also have a variety of image options you can choose from.